# fast-glob not returning expected files

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, glob

I'm developing a vscode extension, and I want to find all files under the current workspace folder, that match the ".ts" extension but exclude `node_modules`

I'm using fast-glob but is not retuning all the expected ".ts" files

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as fg from 'fast-glob';

export class ReferenceManager {
    private suportedExtension = ".ts";
    public projectFolder: vscode.Uri;

    public async updateWorkspaceReferences() {
        let message: string;
        let folders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;

        if (folders && folders.length > 0) {

            this.projectFolder = folders[0].uri;
            console.log(`Updating references for: ${this.projectFolder}`);

            let filepaths = await this.getWorkspaceFilePaths();

            filepaths.forEach(fp => {
                console.log(fp);
            });

            message = '>>> nav-code extension is ready <<<';
        }
        else {
            message = '>>> nav-code extension requires an open workspace to work';
        }
        console.log(message);
    }

    public async getWorkspaceFilePaths(): Promise<string[]> {
        //get all the relevant files of the workspace and convert them to full path
        return (await fg(["**/*" + this.suportedExtension], { ignore: ['**/node_modules'] }) || []).map(x => this.toFullPath(x));
    }

    public toFullPath(relPath: string): string {
        return (this.projectFolder + '/' + relPath);
    }
}
```

The current output is this (only two files)

```
>>nav-code" is gettign ready
Updating references for: file:///c%3A/DATOS/repos/petrel-xml
file:///c%3A/DATOS/repos/petrel-xml/resources/app/out/vscode-dts/vscode.d.ts
file:///c%3A/DATOS/repos/petrel-xml/resources/app/extensions/html-language-features/server/lib/jquery.d.ts
>>> nav-code extension is ready <<<
```

But the folder contains a client and server folder that contains other .ts files
[image]

Is there something wrong with the pattern that I'm using ?

Answer (score 1):

The error was en extra `*` that was not needed after the `/`

```js
suportedExtension = '*.ts' ;

//Then I was calling this
await fg(["**/*" + this.suportedExtension
```

That was buildng this pattern `**/**.ts` but the correct one is `**/*.ts`